# how to check OS is linux or other?

Tags: linux, shell-script

we need to check if the following remote ip's are **linux** OS or other as **win**

example

```
12.43.223.4
23.54.67.3
23.5.6.3
```

we have Linux machine - redhat , and from this machine we need to identify the remote machine if they are Linux or other ?

as I know we can identify by nmap

but I want to find other way since nmap not installed on production machines

so any suggestion how to check remote machine is Linux or other ? ( not by nmap )

Comment: are there any standards enforced at all? Do Windows systems have certain services running? Do Linux ones?

Comment: I can answer on this because win can include diff types

Comment: Are the IP addresses yours?

Comment: You cannot identify by `nmap`. `nmap` can take a guess based on how the remote system responds to certain network traffic but this is a guess and it can be easily fooled.

Comment: NMAP Operating System Detection, while a noble attempt, is fundamentally flawed by reality and simply how Internet protocol works.  It's right there in their readme *When Nmap Guesses Wrong*.

Comment: Is flipping a coin, head or tails, totally out of question?

Comment: defining *flipping a coin*.  what if the coin lands on end propped up against a wall, how do you determine heads or tails ?  The chance is not 100% that the coin will always land as you think it will...  The only standard in the context of this question to work with is IP (internet protocol).

Comment: You give in two different places that you have linux or other or that you have linux or win. There are other options. MacOS, storage devices (often BSD based), network devices (Cisco iOS?) are just a few that we have on our network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in  hostname1 hostname2; 
do 
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $i -A <<'EOF'
uname -a | awk '{if($0 ~ /Linux/){print "Its Linux os"}else{print "its not linux os"}}'
EOF
done
```

Comment: For all that you know, it may be a router between you and the given IP address that answers on port 22 (if anything answers at all). It may not be any of the machines `hostname1` or `hostname2`.

Comment: So if hostname2 is Windows and it's (reasonably enough) not running an SSH service you'll report nothing but an error about not being able to connect.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking;

> How can the operating system of a computer on a network be identified without logging in to it

It cannot.
Any computer system on a network, assuming that network is a typical IP (internet protocol) based on TCP/IP communicates based on that protocol.  And if that is all you have to work with, then:

- a computer on a network can be configured to be invisible first of all, such as not respond to ping among other things,
- but if it does respond or some indication can be seen that there is this computer system on the network, how can you deduce if it is windows, Linux, macOS, Android, other?  You can't: The IP/TCP protocol does not provide for that to happen.

I suppose if a system is somehow configured at a low enough level to include that kind of information in the TCP/IP header in each packet that gets sent out then maybe that can used to work with, but would be very custom.  Otherwise there is no reliable I know of unless you can log in to that system.  If you log in to a system via SSH protocol, well just the same because the SSH protocol is OS-independent, so if you see a computer system responding via SSH on port 22, any computer device with any operating system can do that as long as they follow the SSH protocol which then happens on top of the Internet Protocol.

This is of course is the reason why IP is so great, it allows communication between any device (regardless of operating system) as long as they follow the same *internet protocol*.  An analogy would be I don't need to know if you are male, female, any other characteristic, as long as you follow the a given language protocol (English language in this case) then we can communicate at some level.

You may wish to read the [IPV4 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), in addition to the history of the internet.

Comment: `nmap` tries to identify the OS of remote systems. It often fails so I take exception to the 'can and does' identify OSes.

Comment: It is trivial to spoof nmap, although it is somewhat reliable with unhardened OS